# Find and update JSON object using Typescripts

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Below is my JSON

```
[{  "id": "1",
    "name" : "rob",
    "Lastname":"Xyz"
},
{   "id": "2",
    "name" : "xyz",
    "Lastname":"abc"
}]
```

I have a form where user will enter his first name and last name, what i am trying to achieve here is to check and see if user input info is available in JSON. if yes update with user information else add new object using .push()

Comment: What do you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
export class Test {

    // Objects array
    myObjects = [{  "id": "1",
        "name" : "rob",
        "Lastname":"Xyz"
    },
    {   "id": "2",
        "name" : "xyz",
        "Lastname":"abc"
    }]

    // Method responsible for finding an object who has the name passed in as a parameter
    getIndexByName(name: string): number{
        let index: number;

        this.myObjects.forEach(object => {             
            if(object.name == name){ // Do your filtering here
                index = this.myObjects.indexOf(object);
            }    
        })
        return index;
    }

    updateObject(obj: any){
        let index = this.getIndexByName(obj.name);
        if(index){
            this.myObjects.splice(index,1,obj); // This is the usual function that I use when I find myself needing to 'update' something in an array
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let user = {"id": "2", "name" : "xyz", "Lastname":"yjk"};

this.updateObject(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  Lastname: string;
}

class UsersCollection {

  private id = 15;

  constructor(private _users: Array<User> = []) {

  }

  public create(name: string, lastName: string): User {
    let user =  {
      id: this.id++,
      name: name,
      Lastname: lastName
    };
    this._users.push(user);
    return user;
  }

  public searchUser(name: string, lastName: string): User | null {
    return this._users.find((user) => {
      return user.name == name && user.Lastname == lastName;
    })
  }

  public getOrCreate(name: string, lastName: string) {
    let user = this.searchUser(name, lastName);
    if (user) {
      return user;
    }
    return this.create(name, lastName);
  }

  public size(){
    return this._users.length;
  }
}


let users = new UsersCollection([{
  'id': '1',
  'name': 'rob',
  'Lastname': 'Xyz'
},
  {
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'xyz',
    'Lastname': 'abc'
  }]);

// Existing user
console.log(users.getOrCreate('rob','Xyz'));
console.log(users.size() == 2);

// Add new one
console.log(users.getOrCreate('rob','123'));
console.log(users.size() == 3);
```